# Locale independed float input and boost::program_options/istringstream

Tags: c++, floating-point, locale

I've developed a small application which waits for float values input through command line/boost::program_options .

Also some parts of the application use std::stringstream for formatting floats with required precision.

My question is - do I need special manipulation for proper working of this code on systems with different locale settings ( because of the decimal point separator) ?

I tested my application with different versions of Windows XP localisation, and it's working good (arabic, finnish, china, france, hebrew, korea, deutch, turkey, portugal, spanish, polish, japan, english, russian)

I have found some topics about issues related to float to string and string to float conversion, caused by the decimal separator - and I just want be sure .

Thank you.